# Websocket issue Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, websocket

My app collects news and is fed by a websocket that periodically provides the data to show, the cadence of news is changeable and depends on when the vendors emit them.
When the app is opened in Internet Explorer, if no new items are received, the connection is stopped suddenly after about 20 seconds.

By doing some research I managed to bring the problem back to this specific Internet Explorer behavior:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/804653/rfc6455-websocket-pong-frame

In practice I found that IE sends Pong control frames, but if it does not receive a Ping response, it closes the connection.
Unfortunately I can not change anything server side to handle this unsolicited message, I was wondering if there is a way to handle this abnormal IE behavior from inside my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue happend only if the webSocket remain in idle state for more than 20 secs. We simply raised the frequency of heartbeat messages from the server up to 1 message every 10 secs and the issue never happened again